# SharePoint User Profile Synchronization Service not starting

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, fim, synchronization

I upgraded my user profile service application from SP2010 to SP2013. I upgraded only ProfileDB and Social DB and created a new Sync DB for SP2013.

After creating user profile service,when i tried to start the "User profile synchronization service" it is showing "starting" for few mins and then falls back to Stopped.

I am running the "User Profile Synchronization service" with the Farm account. FIM service is disabled and logged on with Local system account. FIM synchronization service is logged on with farm account.

Farm account has been added to the local admin group,user profile service application's administrator group ,user profile service application's permission group.

On checking the event viewer,I see the below error message when user profile service synchronization service fails to start:

**Performance counters for the FIMSynchronizationService (Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service) service are already in the registry, no need to reinstall. This only happens when you install the same counter twice. The second time install will generate this event.**

How to fix the issue and start the "user profile synchronization service"?

Comment: What do you see in Application event logs regarding this? There must be something there or in ULS logs that cant hint the problem.

Comment: @muhammad zeeshan tahir application event log displays the below error:                      Performance counters for the FIMSynchronizationService (Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service) service are already in the registry, no need to reinstall. This only happens when you install the same counter twice. The second time install will generate this event.

Comment: Alright. Can you give me a little more details about your architecture, SharePoint CU currently installed?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshanTahir I had SP2013 SP1 and SQL server 2014.After installing the latest CU,this issue got resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are many root causes for this issue like**

- The farm account is not added to the local administrator group during starting and provisioning UPS service.
- The User Profile Sync Service account is not a member of the Farm Administrator group.
- Forefront Identity Manager Services are not running.

**Please,** check other root causes and how to overcome this issue at

- [User Profile Synchronization Service Stuck on Starting](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/user-profile-sync-service-stuck-on-starting/)
- [User Profile Synchronization Service Starting then Stopped in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/user-profile-synchronization-service-starting-and-stoped/).

Answer (score 1):

Mine was a known bug with SP2013 SP1 and SQL server 2014.You need to install any of the CU after April 2014 to fix this issue

After installing latest CU,I was able to start the user profile synchronization service without any issue